# Windows Phone 8.1 XAML Ad Mediator

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, admob

I'm trying to integrate AdMediator into an Windows Phone 8.1 XAML project. I installed the AdMediator extension and when i access the Ad Networks it only shows Microsoft Advertising, AdDulex,Smaato. Does this mean Admob does not work inside AdMediator, or it needs to be installed manually.

Comment: AFAIK Admob is supported only on Silverlight WP 8.1 apps. There's no SDK for XAML apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Admob only works on Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight apps. At the moment, there's no SDK for XAML based apps. See [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/bEIlUOW7KTU)